# python mechanize security Questions

Tags: python, mechanize

I am using mechanize to log into a website. I can submit my id and password but it take me to another form that requires me to enter security questions. It is like I am logging in on an unknown pc. Is there a way I can bypass this? Code I am using below sorry had to leave out the website/password details. my code is working but I just don't know if there is away to get past the security questions

```
import sys, mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.open("www.test.com)

br.select_form(nr=1)

br["USERID"] = "xxxxx"
br["PASSWDTXT"] = "xxxxxx"
r = br.submit()
```

Comment: There is no answer to the question in this format. There is no universal way to show/check/skip security question check - it depends on the implementation. You should somehow let us to reproduce and test it.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you are trying to log into someone's website with a valid user/pass but bypass the security questions?